# Submitting a form with enter key

Tags: jquery, html, forms

So I have this HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todo style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="todo script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>To Do List</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm" id="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>`

and this jQuery:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkListForm').keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
            var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
            $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + '<div class="xbox">' + 'X' + '</div>' +  toAdd + '</div>');
            $(".list").sortable();
        }
    });   
    $("#button").click(function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $(".list").append('<div class="item">' + '<div class="xbox">' + 'X' + '</div>' +  toAdd + '</div>');
        $(".list").sortable();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.xbox', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

For some reason, when I press enter (in Chrome), the form doesn't submit; the page refreshes. I've tried various solutions, but none of them work. How can I get the form to submit when enter is pressed?

Comment: "I've tried various solutions" -- what have you tried?

Comment: It's working fine for me.

Comment: I think the enter key is already the default key for submitting a form, even without JavaScript?

Comment: try it again after removing `e.preventDefault();` There is not need to add `keyup` listener. By default on enter key form submits automatically.

Comment: You need to have your submit button formatted correctly. `<input type="submit" value="enter">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter is already the default action for posting a form:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('yes');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="get">
  
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <input type="submit" value="Press enter">
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I can see now that my form wasn't correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

please change the file name either use underscore(_) or hyphen(-) instead of space and try again.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="todo script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have button with type="submit", will submit to the action specified. `<button type="submit">Save</button>`